# How can I find a locally free resolution of $\mathcal{O}_X^\vee \to \mathcal{L}_\bullet$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, vector-bundles, algebraic-vector-bundles

Given a smooth complex projective variety $X$, I want to try and learn how to find a locally free resolution
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_X^\vee \to \mathcal{L}_0 \to \mathcal{L}_1 \to \cdots
$$
The starting cases I'm interested in are smooth hypersurfaces and smooth complete intersections, but I hope to be able to extend this to more cases. Moreover, I am really only interested in finding the first two terms $\mathcal{L}_0,\mathcal{L}_1$ since I only plan on using this resolution for computing $\mathcal{Ext}^i(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{O}_X)$.

---

On second thought, this question is kind of pointless. If I can find a locally free resolution
$$
\mathcal{L}_\bullet \to \mathcal{E} \to 0
$$
then computing $\mathcal{Ext}^i(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})$ is easy, so long as the locally free sheaves come from $\mathbb{P}^n$. This is because
$$
\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{O}(a),\mathcal{F}) \cong \mathcal{F}(-a)
$$
and we have $\mathcal{Hom}$ playing nice with respect to finite direct sums in the first factor.

Comment: I presume when you wrote $\mathcal{O}_X^{\vee}$ you meant the dual of the structure sheaf. But that is just the structure sheaf itself and locally free. So, you could take $L_0=\mathcal{O}_X^{\vee}$ and $L_1=0$. Are you asking for locally free sheaves on projective space? Then, there is none such if $X\neq\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: @Mohan I was looking for locally free sheaves on projective space. Why is this true though?

Comment: If you meant $\mathcal{O}_X^{\vee}$ to be $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_X)=\mathcal{O}_X$, then it is a torsion sheaf over $\mathbb{P}^n$ if $X\neq \mathbb{P}^n$ and thus, it can not be a subsheaf of a locally free sheaf over $\mathbb{P}^n$. If you meant $\mathcal{O}_X^{\vee}=\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n})$, this is zero, so I do not know what information you would get from this.